# SQLite Exception: no such table Error

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Sqlite - “No Such Table” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554269/android-sqlite-no-such-table-error)

We are trying to develop an application on Android. We are using SQLite database and on phone we are getting

> SQLiteException:no such table.

It is working fine on simulator.

Can anyone provide any input on this?

Comment: Have you run your code on a clean emulator? Have you also verified that the code that creates the table is getting executed? The next step would be to get the sqlite db off the emualtor and look at it using a sqlite database browser to check that the table does actually exist.

Comment: Hi! I have already created a database and just using the already created database's, so the table's are already created. I am just doing the SELECT on the existing table. My concern is it is working fine on simulator and not on phone

Comment: Have you verified that the table is there? It is a lot more likely that the table isn't there on the phone than select not working. Again it is very easy to verify that you DB was created correctly.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342346/problem-about-sqlite-databse-no-such-table/4110847#4110847

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't specify the database file name correctly I believe it falls back to creating an empty database. This is generally the cause of 'table not found'. Check your path and database file name.

Comment: i was using eg : data@base-db, so db was not getting created. After i removed @ like database-db, it works for me .... :) thanks for hint...

Answer (score 6):

I had faced a different flavour of the same problem.

I was getting `no such table` error when I try to insert.

Before inserting, the code was calling

```
mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

`getWritableDatabase()` , when called first time will call `onCreate()`

I had my SQL query to create the table within this oncreate method

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            Log.v("INFO1","creating db");
            //Toast.makeText(mCtx, "created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

So for me what had happened was, the `db` was successfully created when the application was first run but no table due to some other errors.
Later whenever the application is run, `onCreate()` is never called as `db` is already there and thus no table created, so all further SQL commands failed.

So I moved creating table out of `onCreate()` , and now its working

Comment: then how did you find db outside oncreate?

Answer (score 2):

Some people have been able to solve the problem using the steps mentioned [here](http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html). It seems to me that this problem exists on certain versions of Android 2.2. I have incorporated this change in my code, though I'm still looking for Beta testers with to see if it actually works.