# problem about sqlite database, no such table: 

Tags: android, sqlite

I open a sqlite database and use rawquery to get data.

But the log.e show the information:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: types:

But, I really have this table.

And i also try to use the other sql ,But also get the error message such as

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: malls:

I am sure there are this two tables.
So why get the error message?

Comment: hey there, what does the rawquery look like?
are the table names "types:" and "malls:" ?

Comment: Do you really create your database with `CREATE TABLE...` ?

Comment: Actually, i already have a database file. So i just put it in the "assets" folder. And i crate a custom SQLiteOpenHelper to copy this file to path : /data/data/com.SGMalls/databases/mallMapv2.sqlite
Then to use Sqlitedatabse.open(); to open this database and try to get data

Comment: The rawquery Cursor cursor=myDataBase.rawQuery(queryString, null);
And i have test this queryString in Sqlitebrowser. It's ok. Can get the data

Comment: This database is large. So this is the problem? Because i write the custom SQLiteOpenHelper from "Using your own SQLite database in Android applications" http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
So the copy file code may be can not copy the complete file.
Yes?

Comment: Could you please tell what solved your problem? I'm stuck in a similar situation and I sure could need some help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is on the emulator, use DDMS File Explorer or `adb pull` to download a copy of the database file and confirm its contents.

> And i crate a custom SQLiteOpenHelper
>   to copy this file to path :
>   /data/data/com.SGMalls/databases/mallMapv2.sqlite

If you are attempting to copy the file in `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onCreate()`, you are too late. I would do it before then.

> So the copy file code may be can not
>   copy the complete file.

It is more likely you would get an error about a corrupt file in that case.

Comment: OK. thanks very much. So. if i want to test this code in device. Also need paste the sqlite database in the device first? O...i need to read a tutorial carefully 
Thanks

Comment: Hi.As you said: I use to ddms file explorer to pull the database file. And i find there are three floder : data,sdcared and system. So any one is ok? and the path of this file also is /data/data/com.SGMalls/databases/mallMapv2.sqlite?
Thanks. Pls help me

Comment: >>>>If you are attempting to copy the file in SQLiteOpenHelper's onCreate(), you are too late. I would do it before then.<<<<<<
THAT WORKED FOR ME THANKS... +1

Comment: @CommonsWare : In my android phone there is not path like data/data. Can that be the reason  "table not found error". Because data/data is not present in my phone, is not able to copy my database from the assets folder into data/data/com.myapp/databases. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple contents providers, you might think that your table exists while it does not. In which case the error you are getting is legitimate.

Take a look here for details and solution:
http://devserghini.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-sqliteopenhelper-and-multiple.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this error occurs when you change the table structure. To solve this, clean the data
(*Settings* -> *Manage application* -> *Clear data*) before installing the new application.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()` interpretation takes a single string sql, ending with ";". Two lines have not interpreted.

Creating tables in a few lines sql just not executed.