# Using SQLite to store userEvents, getting an SQLiteException

Tags: android, sqlite, dao, sqliteopenhelper

I'm having trouble with my SQLite database. First I'm fairly new to DBs and I adapted a best practices tutorial to my situation. I ended up with some DAOs and a dataManager to interact with the tables.

I have 3 tables an Event Task and Person table, my Person and task tables have not problem being added to the DB. But when I try to do the main table (event) it give me this error.

```
07-24 16:55:55.055: E/AndroidRuntime(10053): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: event: , while compiling: insert into event (logging_user, location, initial_time, _id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

So I have a constant used for each table (I think you have to) so my eventTable does exist with the name "event". What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked multiple times here. Please see if this : [problem about sqlite database, no such table:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342346/problem-about-sqlite-database-no-such-table)  helps to address your problem.