# Sqlite do not read more than one cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new on Android. I have Application and it connected with sqlite expert database.I added my db on assets folder. My problem is first cursor is reading but program never read second cursor.

I am looking this question but I did not find my answer
[problem about sqlite database, no such table:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342346/problem-about-sqlite-database-no-such-table)

```
package com.qozix.data;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.qozix.sqlite.DataBaseHelper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class ClassRepository {

    private List<ClassData> classDataList=new ArrayList<ClassData>();
    private List<EventData> EventDataList=new ArrayList<EventData>();
    private Context myContext;
    private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;

    public ClassRepository(Context context) {
        myContext=context;
        dataBaseHelper=new DataBaseHelper(context);
        loadData();
        loadData2();
    }
    public void loadData(){
        try {

            dataBaseHelper.openDataBase();
            SQLiteDatabase database=dataBaseHelper.getMyDataBase();
            String[] columns={"_id","name","x","y"};
            Cursor cursor=database.query("classroom", columns,null , null, null, null, null, null);
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                int _id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                String codename= name;
                int x=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("x"));
                int y=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("y"));
                String message=""+_id+" "+name+" "+x+" "+y;
                Log.i("[InDoorMap]", message);
                classDataList.add(new ClassData(codename,name,x,y));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("[InDoorMap]", "Database exception first cursor ",e);
        }       
    }

    public void loadData2(){
        try {

            dataBaseHelper.openDataBase();
            SQLiteDatabase database=dataBaseHelper.getMyDataBase();
                String[] column2={"_id","description","hour","name"};
                Cursor cursor2=database.query("events", column2,null , null, null, null, null, null);
                while(cursor2.moveToNext()){
                    int _id1=cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                    String description=cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));
                    String hour = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("hour"));
                    String nameevent = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                    String message2=""+_id1+" "+description+" "+hour+" "+nameevent;
                    Log.i("[event]", message2);
                    System.out.println(message2);
                    EventDataList.add(new EventData(nameevent,hour,description));
                    Log.e("[InDoorMap]", "Evente girmedi");
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("[InDoorMap]", "Database exception secon cursor ",e);
        }       
    }

}
```

[image]

taken Assets folder

�StableeventseventsCREATE TABLE [events] (

This is log cat

```
05-06 00:12:33.598: (29244): Database already exists 
05-06 00:12:33.598: (29244): Database opened. 
05-06 00:12:44.910: (29244): 1 PigastroCafe 1336 1688 // it read other table
05-06 00:12:44.910: (29244): 2 Pigastro 540 344
05-06 00:12:44.910: E/SQLiteLog(29244): (1) no such table: events
05-06 00:12:44.926: (29244): Database exception secon cursor 
05-06 00:12:44.926: (29244): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: events (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, description, hour, name FROM events
05-06 00:12:44.926: (29244):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-06 00:12:44.926: (29244):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
```

And this my databasehelper class It connection on this page. I really did not find problem :(((

```
package com.qozix.sqlite;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.util.Log;


public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    //The Android's default system path of your application database.


    private static String DB_NAME = "KhasIndoor6";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  public SQLiteDatabase getMyDataBase() {
        return myDataBase;
    }

/**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            Log.i("[InDoorMap]", "Database already exists ");
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            Log.i("[InDoorMap]", "Database created ");
            try {

                copyDataBase();

                Log.i("[InDoorMap]", "Database copied ");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("[InDoorMap]", "Database exception ",e);
                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath =  myContext.getFilesDir().getPath() +"/"+ DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            myDataBase=checkDB;
        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = myContext.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/" + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        File outFile=new File(outFileName);
        Log.i("[InDoorMap]", "Output file "+outFile.getAbsolutePath()+" "+outFile.exists()+" "+outFile.length());
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = myContext.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/" + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


}
```

Comment: seems pretty clear. your table does not exist. how do you create it ?

Comment: yes it exist when I open my db folder it is showing http://imageshack.com/a/img843/3015/mhqh.jpg

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img842/5728/33fq.jpg this my table field

Comment: Are you able to access classroom table??

Comment: you are not closing database and cursor handle. Please close after your data has been retrieved.

Comment: Where is your table name ..

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img843/3484/h9if.jpg it is show database and read first cursor.. but I never understand why do not read second cursor

Comment: and I am sending you my database on dropbox

Comment: how is your database in the app related to the assets folder?

Comment: class DataBaseHelper  is connected asset folder and it connected database but never read second table

Answer (score 0):

Close Cursor and database handle after your operation has been done. change your query as shown in below code.
Use following code.

```
package com.qozix.data;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.qozix.sqlite.DataBaseHelper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class ClassRepository {

    private List<ClassData> classDataList=new ArrayList<ClassData>();
    private List<EventData> EventDataList=new ArrayList<EventData>();
    private Context myContext;
    private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;

    public ClassRepository(Context context) {
        myContext=context;
        dataBaseHelper=new DataBaseHelper(context);
        loadData();
        loadData2();
    }
    public void loadData(){
        try {

            dataBaseHelper.openDataBase();
            SQLiteDatabase database=dataBaseHelper.getMyDataBase();
            String[] columns={"_id","name","x","y"};
            Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("select _id,name,x,y from classroom",null);
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                int _id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                String codename= name;
                int x=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("x"));
                int y=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("y"));
                String message=""+_id+" "+name+" "+x+" "+y;
                Log.i("[InDoorMap]", message);
                classDataList.add(new ClassData(codename,name,x,y));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("[InDoorMap]", "Database exception first cursor ",e);
        }       
       dataBaseHelper.close();
       cursor.close();
    }

    public void loadData2(){
        try {

            dataBaseHelper.openDataBase();
            SQLiteDatabase database=dataBaseHelper.getMyDataBase();
                String[] column2={"_id","description","hour","name"};
                                Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("select _id,description,hour,name from events",null);
                while(cursor2.moveToNext()){
                    int _id1=cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                    String description=cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));
                    String hour = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("hour"));
                    String nameevent = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                    String message2=""+_id1+" "+description+" "+hour+" "+nameevent;
                    Log.i("[event]", message2);
                    System.out.println(message2);
                    EventDataList.add(new EventData(nameevent,hour,description));
                    Log.e("[InDoorMap]", "Evente girmedi");
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("[InDoorMap]", "Database exception secon cursor ",e);
        }     
       dataBaseHelper.close();
       cursor2.close();  
    }

}
```

Comment: Be sure that your table is created when you are accessing data from it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ykhzamyibazot8/KhasIndoor6 yes I am sure I will be crazy :(( When I look it I show it

Comment: You are calling getMyDataBase() this method it is commented

Comment: which part there are lots of place I called it ? getMyDataBase() ?

Comment: and it is not commented   public SQLiteDatabase getMyDataBase() {
  return myDataBase;
 }

Comment: I send you my database on dropbox