# while adding new table in new realease error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my android app, I have used SQLite database in the initial versions. I need to create a new table now in the app. I have given create statement in onCreate() and onUpgrate(), but both are not wroking and I am getting the error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table
```

I tried, try...catch() which is also not working.
Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Do you set the database version? As far as i know onUpgrade() calls if the old db version is less than newer db version

Comment: add some code. then only we can identify what is the error.

Comment: Thanks Madushan, setting new db version solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By searching the error line you can find other same solved questions on stackoverflow. 
take a look at: [[problem about sqlite database, no such table:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342346/problem-about-sqlite-database-no-such-table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342346/problem-about-sqlite-database-no-such-table)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a reason that your table is already created.... try a new test app with this code (worked for me)

make a Test app with only one button which create a table

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   SQLiteDatabase objConnection=openOrCreateDatabase("database_name",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
objConnection.execSQL("Create Table IF NOT EXISTS table_name(id INTEGER primary Key AUTOINCREMENT, name Varchar(200))");
objConnection.close();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "db created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
});
}
```