# "No Such Table" Error found in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to learn about SQLite databases, but I really hate dealing with any back-end stuff, with a passion. I'm already hitting walls with a seemingly simple problem.

Here is the code that I think matters from the `DatabaseHelper` class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Library";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "books";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String AUTHOR = "author";
    public static final String ISBN = "isbn";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, author TEXT, isbn TEXT)");
    }


    public boolean insertBook(String title, String author, String isdn) {

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(TITLE, title);
            cv.put(AUTHOR, author);
            cv.put(ISBN, isdn);

            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
            db.close();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code in my main activity

```
dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

dbHelper.insertBook("Harry Potter", "JK", "1000");
dbHelper.insertBook("Hamlet", "Shakespeare", "500");
```

Eclipse is telling me that there is an error in the `insertBook()` method. It says that there is `no such table books: ...`. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. What makes it more frustrating is that only a couple of minutes before it was working perfectly, then (I think) I dropped the table and it just create it again for whatever reason, even though this code has not changed since I first created it (I think...).

Comment: Can you add the actual stacktrace?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is an older version of the database on your device, which does have the (empty) database in place, but not the books table. If that's an option for you, just uninstall and reinstall the app.

Later, when you'd like to add a new table to the database during production on end-user devices, but keep existing data, the designated hook to add new tables, alter the schema or upgrade your data is the `onUpgrade` method of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: I have the onUpgrade method but I get this error every time I add some table to my database. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067152/no-such-table-error-whenever-i-add-some-table-to-my-db) you can see my code and my error. What should I put in onUpgrade to avoid this error?

Answer (score 5):

I have written a ORM framework for that. https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman

You can easily write Android applications using SQLite with that. It uses your Java classes (Book, in this case) as database tables (entities).

It even creates your table automatically and you just say `book1.insert()`, done.

Answer (score 5):

You must uninstall the applcation and then reinstall it. It should work after that.

Answer (score 1):

try this one 
for example for insert:

```
 public boolean insertBook(String title, String author, String isdn) {

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(TITLE, title);
            cv.put(AUTHOR, author);
            cv.put(ISBN, isdn);

            ***try
             {
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
 catch ( SQLiteException e)
        {
            onCreate(db);
  db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}***

            db.close();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing about this made any sense, as the table existed from the very beginning of the DB, so we tried different things:**

> 1. uninstalling app
> 2. claning cache / data
> 3. changing database version number
> 4. forcing to copy the database even if it already existed

Answer (score 1):

Also had the issue where I already had the app built with an existing DB, but wanted to add another table.

Besides having the `onUpgrade` method, I also had to increment the `private static final Integer DB_VERSION`, which is used when instantiating the DatabaseHelper, like so:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}
```

Also from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java), my `onUpgrade` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // on upgrade drop older tables
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_1);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_2);

    // create new tables
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Then, after building the app, the new version of the database worked.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason, you dropped the table, you might want to delete the database to force the application to recreate it correctly. Use `adb shell` and find the database in `/data/data/[package_name]/databases/`. You can just delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but cleaning the project did not fixed it.
It turned out I passed `DATABASE_NAME` instead of `TABLE_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `onCreate` method called. I am also facing similar type of problem when creating multiple table. If you create a separate class make sure you first clear all the storage data of your app and then again run it ..It will work fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Note:

External Database You Access Time must add for the path in **Sqliteopenhelper class**

public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.shortcuts/databases/";

com.example.shortcuts=Your Package name

Comment: Welcome to SO. To ensure high-quality answers, please ensure that you use full sentences and shortly relate to the question. Pure code fragments are not too helpful, so please edit. PS: I fixed the typesetting for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
db.execSQL(
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, author TEXT, isbn TEXT)"
);
```

remove space after the table name, it should be like this.

```
db.execSQL(
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, author TEXT, isbn TEXT)"
);
```