# Android: No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, file

I have created my sqlite database (`employeertest.sql`) and puted it  in the `Assets` folder, then run
this code.

Unfortunately in the line `getBaseContext().getAssets().open("employeertest")` compiler says `No such file or directory`

```
 try {
                String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() +"/databases";
                File f = new File(destPath);

                    f.mkdirs();
                    f.createNewFile();

                    //---copy the db from the assets folder into 
                    // the databases folder---


                        CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("employeertest"),
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/employeertest"));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Try using double slashes or double backslashes as separators in the directory string.

Comment: Try with getBaseContext().getAssets().open("employeertest.sql")...you need the file extension.

Comment: @JanBo ok it solves my problem but now it sayes `no such table : test`
for a query `select * from test`

Comment: Well you either dont have that table in your db :) which i highly doubt or you dint correctly initialize the database from file. Post you db opening code and query code.

Comment: @JanBo actully i have, i made my database using firefox plugin.
please take a look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934237/sqlite-exception-no-such-table-error

Comment: Please update your question with relative parts of the code, without it i cant help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("employeertest.sql")
```

instead? Considering the file doesn't exist, I'm assuming the extension is missing and it cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Context.getDatabasePath(String)` to retrieve the correct path to the database directory. Please be aware that the directory could also not be there when you try to copy the db from the assets